# each и замена значений внутри span

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть вот такой код :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.update-plugins').each(function(){
        if ($(this).data('url')) {
            $.get( $(this).data('url'), function( data ) {
                $(this).children('.plugin-count').text(data);  
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="background: green;" class="update-plugins count-2" data-url="/getQMails/index.php" title="Писем в очереди на отправку..."><span class="plugin-count"></span></span>
```

Не работает, хотя по адресу `/getQMails/index.php` в AJAX-запросе выдается нужное значение, где-то напутал в строчке:

```
$(this).children('.plugin-count').text(data);
```

Comment: this внутри колбэка `get` это не элеменнт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.update-plugins').each(function(){
        var $oldThis = $(this);
        if ($(this).data('url')) {
            $.get( $(this).data('url'), function( data ) {
                $oldThis.children('.plugin-count').text(data);  
            });
        }
    });
});
```

У Вас $(this) указывало на AJAX  объект.

Comment: пробовал результат такой же ничего не изменяется

Comment: Спасибо за решение!

Comment: обновил ответ, другая ошибка

Comment: Закройте вопрос. Не за что

Answer (score 1):

`this` внутри колбэка get это не html элемент.
Сохраните его перед использованием.

```
$('.update-plugins').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data('url')) {
        $.get( $this.data('url'), function( data ) {
            $this.children('.plugin-count').text(data);  
        });
    }
});
```